# $f, g$ are convex and positive $\Rightarrow f(x)g(y)$ is convex?

Tags: convex-analysis

Prove or provide a counterexample: if $f$ and $g$ are real convex positive functions on some intervals, then $f(x)g(y)$ is convex.

Comment: I think if you throw in the assumption that theyr'e also increasing, the product is convex (?).  This is a standard theorem in any text on convex analysis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f(x)=x$, $g(x)=1-x$ is a counterexample on $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $(fg)''=f''g+2f'g'+fg''$ it's sufficient for $fg$ to be convex that additionally $f'g'\geq0$, i.e., both are decreasing or both are increasing.